# How to fill the values to a shell script from tsv file and create new file from 1st column value

Tags: bash, awk

I have a data.tsv file with 100 entries, as below

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD | ColumnE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 31 | Cell 4 | Cell 3 | Cell 5 | Cell 8 |
| Cell 21 | Cell 2 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 | Cell 9 |

and I have a template.in script below, that need to fill above values from tsv file

```
for_example = $ColumnA
testmyhpothesis = $ColumnB $ColumnC
cleandir = $ColumnD $ColumnE
testOutdir = /path/todir/$ColumnD
```

And create new script file with columnA value

eg:
File 1. **Cell 31.in**

```
for_example = Cell 31
testmyhpothesis = Cell 4 Cell 3
cleandir = Cell 5 Cell 8
testOutdir = /path/todir/Cell 5
```

File 2. **Cell 21.in**

```
for_example = Cell 21
testmyhpothesis = Cell 2 Cell 5
cleandir = Cell 6 Cell 9
testOutdir = /path/todir/Cell 6
```

```
awk -F '\t' '{for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {print $i >> new_file} data.tsv
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what the point of generating 100 scripts is, when you can loop over the TSV file and do your stuff in there?

Comment: @Fravadona I want to create individual files to use them differently

Comment: The script files you show are not valid bash syntax. And the `awk` script you show has nothing to do with your goal. Please edit your question, fix your example bash scripts (execute them, maybe, until they run without errors and do what they are supposed to do), and show your real `awk` code.

Comment: Yes, `ColumnA` values are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\t" }
NR == FNR {
    tmplt[++numLines] = $0
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    for ( fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++ ) {
        tag = "$" $fldNr
        tags2fldNrs[tag] = fldNr
    }
    next
}
{
    out = $(tags2fldNrs["$ColumnA"]) ".in"
    for ( lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++ ) {
        line = tmplt[lineNr]
        for ( tag in tags2fldNrs ) {
            if ( s = index(line,tag) ) {
                fldNr = tags2fldNrs[tag]
                val = $fldNr
                line = substr(line,1,s-1) val substr(line,s+length(tag))
            }
        }
        print line > out
    }
    close(out)
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk template.in data.tsv
```

```
$ head Cell*
==> Cell 21.in <==
#!/bin/bash

for_example = Cell 21
testmyhpothesis = Cell 2 Cell 5
cleandir = Cell 6 Cell 9
testOutdir = /path/todir/Cell 6

==> Cell 31.in <==
#!/bin/bash

for_example = Cell 31
testmyhpothesis = Cell 4 Cell 3
cleandir = Cell 5 Cell 8
testOutdir = /path/todir/Cell 5
```

That would fail if you could have column tags (names) that are substrings of others, e.g. `ColumnA` and `ColumnAB`, and it assumes the values under `ColumnA` are always unique. That's consistent with the example you provided so post a new question if your example is wrong and you can't figure out how to adapt this to suit your real data.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that makes use of `envsubst` for replacing the `$ColumnXXX` in `template.in`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
{
    # get the names of the variables from the TSV header
    IFS=$'\t' read -r -a varnames
    export "${varnames[@]}" || exit 1

    # read each field into its corresponding variable
    while IFS=$'\t' read -r "${varnames[@]}"
    do
        # replace the expansions in "template.in"
        envsubst "${varnames[*]/#/$}" < template.in > "${!varnames[0]}.in"
    done
} < data.tsv
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, my apologies, I have made few changes in the query

Comment: @devbasic I updated my answer. In fact it's a lot easier now